Getting SOP-330023 Error when sending a request
I am trying to make a SOAP call from Postman that subscribes a user to a service in Adobe, it looks like this:

These are the headers I am using:

And I am receiving message after firing:

'SOP-330023 An error occurred during the SOAP call. You don't have the required rights to view the detail.'


I am not sure why I am getting this message, I've made similar calls using this same endpoint and headers and have not had a problem until now. I also can't seem to find anything regarding this on the internet.
Can anyone help?
I've tried adding login credentials to the body but I keep getting the same message.
